# Can I use regular expression for job name dependency in IBM LSF?

Tags: lsf

I have a job which is supposed to be dependent on DONE state of multiple LSF Jobs having name prefix similar, let's say,

job 'A' depends on jobs with names 'Job-1', 'Job-2', 'Job-3',....,'Job-100'

Can I use following regex in defining job dependency for Job 'A'?

```
Job-*
```

Something like,

```
bsub -J 'A' -w "done(Job-*)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_command_ref/bsub.w.1.html)

> Use double quotes (") around job names that begin with a number. In
>   the job name, specify the wildcard character asterisk (*) at the end
>   of a string, to indicate all jobs whose name begins with the string.
>   For example, if you use jobA* as the job name, it specifies jobs named
>   jobA, jobA1, jobA_test, jobA.log, etc.